# Retry function when string not found

Tags: php, curl

I have a function that scrapes data using a list of proxies with curl. It selects a random proxy each time the function is called. However sometimes a proxy can fail or timeout.

When the connection fails/timeout I would like to repeat the function up to 3 times until the data is returned.

The way I would like to test if the connection is bad is by checking if a string exists in the output like this:

```
$check = stripos($page,'string_to_check');
if($check > 0){ 
    return $page; //String found. Return scraped data. 
}
else { 
    //String not found. Loop the script 
}
```

How would I get the whole function code to repeat if the string doesn't exist?

Comment: turn in to recursive function

Comment: `$i = 3; while ($i--) { ... }`

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$max_tries = 3;
$success = false;

//try 3 times
for( $i = 0; $i < $max_tries; $i++ ) {
  $page = your_scrape_function();
  $check = stripos($page,'string_to_check');
  if($check > 0){
    $success = true;
    break; //String found. Break loop.
  }
}

// double check that the string was actually found and you didn't just exceed $max_tries
if( ! $success ) {
  die('Error: String not found or scrape unsuccessful.');
}
```

Comment: Problem with this is that the function seems to select the same dead proxy each retry.